# How to turn off auto refresh with Gridx with JSONRest store?

Tags: dojo, dojo.gridx, jsonreststore

I am using Gridx with a JSONRest store.

Does anyone know how to turn off the auto refresh function of the Gridx with the JSONRest store?

I want to add and remove multiple rows at a time.  However, every time I call grid.store.add() or grid.store.remove(), the grid automatically refreshes the JSONRest store.

This is undesirable for me because my servers do not have time to put all of the records in the database before the query is run again by Gridx so only a few of the new records actually show up in the grid.

I want to turn off the auto refresh function of the JSONRest store and then do it manually later.

Thanks